# WPF - Is there a workaround to apply Font weight to Arrial narrow / Calibri light font families?

Tags: wpf, fonts

It looks like for Arrial narrow or Calibri light FontFamilies, WPF does not apply Bold or Italic. Is there any work around to do that? I'm sure there are other FontFamilies with this problem.

```xml
<FontFamily x:Key="SelectedFontFamily">Calibri light</FontFamily>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SelectedFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
</Style>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Thin"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - Thin - 100"/>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="UltraLight"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - UltraLight - 200" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraLight"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - ExtraLight - 200" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Light"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - Light - 300" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - Normal - 400" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Regular"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - Regular - 400" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - Medium - 500" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="DemiBold"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - DemiBold - 600" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="SemiBold"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - SemiBold - 600" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - Bold - 700"/>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="UltraBold"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - UltraBold - 800" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraBold"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - ExtraBold - 800" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Heavy"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - Heavy - 900" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Black"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - Black - 900" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraBlack"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - ExtraBlack - 950" />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="UltraBlack"  Text="Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz - UltraBlack - 950" />
</StackPanel>
```

The result for this is:

[image: result image]

Comment: Fonts don't always have definitions for all the options. If you pick a font and set it to bold or italic and nothing happens then this is the likely reason. The work round would be to use a different font which does contain those options.

Comment: @Andy I think Calibri Light does have a bold version, at least available in Microsoft Office. Or maybe Office is performing some processing to create a bolded version that WPF doesn't?

Comment: In PowerPoint if you set bold/italic for this two fonts, it changes accordingly. WPF doesn't.

Comment: There is only Calibri on my system. If you use fontfamily calibri instead, does that give you the expected result?

Comment: And I only have Arial

Comment: When you look in fonts. What are these fonts called? The name might not be what you're expecting. EG Arial MT Std Light is a lightg weight arial font by agfa monotype

Comment: @Andy, if I set fontFamily to Calibri, than yes, it works. But there are some FontFamilies that WPF can't apply FontWeight. And I would like to find if there is a workarround for that, besides changing it to Calibri.

Comment: If you're using the correct font family name and it doesn't work then the only practical work round I can think of would be to use a different font family. Obtain a different font ttf if necessary. If you're seeing something work elsewhere then the chances are that the font family name is not what you think it is. The alternative is what? Your other software somehow dynamically builds it's own representation of a font.